# Aurelia: How to nest a plugin (B) inside another plugin (A)?

Tags: plugins, aurelia

Anyone know how to nest and configure a plugin (B) inside another plugin (A), using Aurelia?

My problem arises if plugin B was installed by JSPM as a consequence of being a dependency of plugin A (as opposed to plugin B being installed as a dependency of the application that is using plugin A).

What happens is that when the Aurelia framework tries to load plugin B (from within the `configure` method of plugin A), it can't find it.  It fails at the module loader level.

If, on the other hand, plugin B is installed as a dependency at the application level, then when plugin A tries to load plugin B the loader has no problem finding it.

Code in plugin A might look like the following:

```
export function configure(frameworkConfig: FrameworkConfiguration)
{
    frameworkConfig.plugin("plugin B");
}
```

I would prefer not to require the application to have such a direct dependency upon plugin B, rather, would prefer that this dependency be managed by plugin A.

Suggestions appreciated, including any suggestions of a better design pattern that might also avoid this problem.

Comment: It's hard to tell without more information. Could you give us some code or perhaps the name of the libraries?

Comment: Hi @Doug Kent did you import it using au cli?

Comment: @janmvtrinidad No I didn't import anything using au cli.

Comment: @FabioLuz See a bit of code I added to the original question, above

Comment: @DougKent In case of aurelia-cli, dependencies of plugin is also need to add in aurelia.json so it will added in bundle, in that case it seems you need to add it too in your bundle. Consider this [plugin](https://github.com/Malexion/aurelia-table) and here is the [output](https://github.com/Malexion/aurelia-table/tree/master/dist/amd) of the plugin, it only contains all the code needed for the plugin but it does not contain dependencies. So for the plugin you will need to include it in your  bundle.

Comment: For this [plugin](https://github.com/michaelmalonenz/aurelia-dragula/blob/master/package.json#L88), it adds aurelia configuration in package.json. So when aurelia CLI, reads it, it will automatically added in bundle. So when a plugin has a dependencies it needs to be included in bundle.

Comment: @janmvtrinidad Thanks for your efforts, but neither of the examples you gave conform to the use case.  I added a snippet of code to the original question, above, that makes more clear what is the goal.